# How are zero-score answers arranged in a question?

Tags: support, sorting

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085882/how-to-create-a-parent-div-for-selected-multiple-child/72086244#72086244), I was the first one to answer it but multiple people gave their solutions. No answer got any votes but if you use the Highest Score filter it shows a random answer on top instead of the first (my) answer. I just wanted to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All answers except the deleted one have the same score i.e. 0. So when you sort by score they are all equal. To give every answer an equal chance the system [sorts them randomly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118835/what-is-the-sort-order-of-the-answers) in that case.